# r remove columns with empty vector of indeces

Tags: r

We all know how to exclude columns from a matrix using a vector of column indices:

```
v=c(1,3)
a = matrix(rnorm(12),nrow=3)
a[,-v]
```

But when the indexing vector is empty, the return matrix is empty:

```
v = numeric()
a[,-v]
# returns matrix with 0 columns
```

How can i get the returned matrix to be the original matrix when the excluded set of column indices is empty?

**There must be a fancier way than using the cumbersome `if else`:**

```
if (length(v)==0) {
    b = a
} else {
    b = a[,-v]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We could create an index with `setdiff`

```
j1 <- setdiff(seq_len(ncol(a)), v)
```

and then subset 'a'

```
a[, j1, drop = FALSE]
```

Answer (score 0):

reline the previous command and you should be good